# Подсоединить сигнал всем виджетам

Tags: c++, qt

Как подсоединить сигнал ( через `connect`) всем виджетам определенного класса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если все виджеты имеют общий родительский элемент, то можно использовать функцию [`findChildren()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

```
QList<QPushButton*> allPButtons = parentWidget.findChildren<QPushButton*>();
for (auto button : allPButtons) {
  connect(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного дополню ответ @PavelParshin. Может случиться, что мы хотим обойти все виджеты определённого класса, имеющиеся в программе, но родитель у них не один, а вручную перечислять всех родителей в программе не хочется. Тогда подойдёт следующий код:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Q> void processAllWidgets(std::function<void(Q*)> func)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<QObject, Q>::value, 
                  "Template argument must be derived from QObject!");

    if (func != nullptr)
    {
        for (auto w : QApplication::topLevelWidgets())
        {
            if (Q* q = qobject_cast<Q*>(w))
                func(q);
            for (auto q : w->findChildren<Q*>())
                func(q);
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь `Q` - класс-потомок `QObject`, `func` - функция (функтор), которая принимает указатель на объект типа `Q` или его потомка и ничего не возвращает.

Особо отмечу, что метод `QObject::findChildren<T>()` обходит "детей" рекурсивно, без ограничения уровня вложенности.